# Detox + android Compiling DetoxTest.java fails

Tags: react-native, detox

I'm trying to run

`detox build -c android.emu.release`

but it fails when it tries to compile `DetoxTest.java` with the following errors

```
  ~/android/app/src/androidTest/java/<package_name>/DetoxTest.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, false, false);
                            ^
      symbol:   class MainActivity
      location: class DetoxTest

  ~/android/app/src/androidTest/java/<package_name>/DetoxTest.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, false, false);
                                                                                 ^
  symbol:   class MainActivity
  location: class DetoxTest
```

I tried importing MainActivity from the package but I get the package cannot be found.

RN 0.51.1
Detox: 7.4.3

Comment: Have you ever managed to fix this? I have the same problem with detox 8.1.5 and react native 0.56

Comment: Never mind, this is just me, I forgot to change package com.example at the top to my package name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To solve this issue, follow closely the [README for wix/detox/AndroidSupportStatus](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/More.AndroidSupportStatus.md)

For example if your project name is **myandroidproject** (see property rootProject.name of settings.gradle below), DetoxTest.java will be at the following location inside the package com.myandroidproject.

**android/app/src/androidTest/java/com/myandroidproject/DetoxTest.java**

```
package com.myandroidproject
```

...

**settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'myandroidproject'
```

...

In your case above, you have to replace **package_name** appropriately.

Comment: This help me thank you. once i got stuck building the release version of my apk then I try using debug mode to run my E2E. first time build the debug mode failed. Once follow this it works I miss the package name inside the detox. Thank u mate

Answer (score 2):

Another issue can be if the `rootProject.name` has capital letters, like `rootProject.name = 'SomeName'`. Then it should be `package com.somename`

Answer (score 0):

Along with making sure my project name was correct in my import statements, I also had to change my directories to match my package name. Somehow I was able to build the project with a folder name different than my project name in the past but detox wasn't okay with this.

Import statement:

```
package com.my_package_name
```

Corresponding folder structures:

```
android/app/src/main/java/com/my_package_name
android/app/src/androidTest/java/com/my_package_name
```